# Display two text files row by row

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using wordpress and at the moment I've got 2 text files. First one is the_content(); while the second text file is scraped from an external source.

At the moment, I display both texts side by side in 2 columns. However, I want to display them one after another in rows.

e.g

```
row1[content]
row1[external]
row2[content]
row2[external]
...
...
rown[content]
rown[external]
```

.

---

I use the code below to scrap the text file from external source :

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
  @$html->loadHtmlFile($url); 
  $xpath = new DOMXPath( $html );
  $rows = $xpath->query( '/html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[1]|//*[@id="content"]'); 
  foreach ($rows as $row){ 
    echo $html->saveHtml($row)."\n"; 
  }
```

Is it possible to display one row from the_content() and afterwards another row from external source in wordpress? if so can someone please help me out. thanks in advance

Comment: In addition, both content and external source has same structure. As in if split into rows then they will have same number of rows

Comment: use a for loop or while loop and print $row_from_content[$i] and $row_from_external[$i] where $i is incremented from 0 to count($row)